# Storage of important documents in Mexico

Tags: safety, luggage-storage, lost-documents, mexico-city

I'm going to Mexico soon on a solo trip and I want to explore the country as much as I can.

One concern for me is my residence permit. I need it to come back to France (where I actually live). If I ever lose it, it will then be such a hard process for me to come back because I'd need a visa and **the French embassy would not give it to me in less than at least 3 months,** (which is intolerable for my employer).

So basically my question is: where can I store safely such an important document in CDMX?". I know I can just carry it with me all the time, but since I travel alone this would made me way too cautious and my trip less adventurous (for example I will have to forget about all the water activities).

I have also heard about airport lockers but I don't know if they are safe and cane be trusted for a period of 20 days.

If anyone has an idea or a hint, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could wear a hidden pocket, travel or money belt (some of which are waterproof). Depending on your accommodations during the trip, consider those that offer in-room safes and, if not available in room, check what ‘behind the desk’ storage provisions are available.  Many hostels offer lockers; if you haven’t brought your own padlock, some have them available, or buy one locally.  Another option might be private security box or deposit box rentals, not affiliated with banks. A Google search for Mexico City returned [SwissBoxes](https://www.swissboxes.com/en/.php) or [StrongMax](https://www.strongmax.com.mx/services).